# C++ to Javascript (Simple Mortgage Calculator )

Tags: javascript, jquery, c++, calculator

I am very new at JavaScript. I have made a mortgage calculator on C language. Now I want to use on my website using Javascript. It's looking like this 
http://prntscr.com/9820of
[image: a busy cat]

so Inputs are

-Purchase price: (exmp: $100000)

-Down Payment: (exmp: 20%) [so the loan will be $80,000]

-Mortgage Term: (exmp: 20year)

-Interest Rate: (4.5%) - by default 4.5% - user can change it

-Property Tax: (1% of the Purchase price) - (by default 1% - user can change it)

-P.Insurance : (exmp: $1500 - yearly) - (by default $1500 - user can change it)

And output will be(after clicking "calculate" these will appear below the calculate button):

-Monthly Principle + Interest:

-Monthly Tax :

-Monthly Ins :

-Total Payment: (monthly)

And here is my C++ code for this:

```
int main()
{
float  year,interest_rate,price,paid,payable,property_tax,annual_insurance,paid_in_percent,
mi,base,mbase,i,
pi,monthly_tax,monthly_insurance,monthly_total;

cout << "Purchase price: ";
cin >> price;
cout << "Down payment: ";
cin >> paid_in_percent;
cout << "Mortage term: ";
cin >> year;
cout << "Interest rate: ";
cin >> interest_rate;
cout << "Property tax: ";
cin >> property_tax;
cout << "Property insurance: ";
cin >> annual_insurance;

mi = interest_rate/1200;
base = 1;
mbase = 1 + mi;
paid = (price*paid_in_percent)/100;
for (i=0; i<year*12; i++){
    base = base * mbase;
}
pi = (price - paid) * mi / ( 1 - (1/base));
monthly_tax = (property_tax*price) / (1200*year);
monthly_insurance = annual_insurance / 12;
monthly_total = pi + monthly_tax + monthly_insurance;

cout << "Monthly prin + int: " << pi << endl;
cout << "Monthly tax: " << monthly_tax << endl;
cout << "Monthly insurance: " << monthly_insurance << endl;
cout << "Total Payment: " << monthly_total << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: All the logic in this looks like you could literally just copy & paste into _JavaScript_, all you really need to change is how you're setting initial values

Comment: Is it possible to do with only Javascript? Or I need to do the logics on PHP and then I'll have to bring values by ajax?

Comment: This is C++ not the "C language".

Comment: Yeah! Actually it's not a big deal without some syntax and OOP.

Answer (score 1):

All the logic in this looks like you could literally just copy & paste into *JavaScript*, all you really need to change is how you're setting initial values

Here it is transcribed using `prompt` for input and `alert` for output. The `+` before `prompt` is casting to *Number*.

```
function main() {
    var year, interest_rate, price, paid, payable, property_tax, annual_insurance, paid_in_percent,
        mi, base, mbase, i,
        pi, monthly_tax, monthly_insurance, monthly_total;

    // input
    price            = +prompt("Purchase price: ");
    paid_in_percent  = +prompt("Down payment: ");
    year             = +prompt("Mortage term: ");
    interest_rate    = +prompt("Interest rate: ");
    property_tax     = +prompt("Property tax: ");
    annual_insurance = +prompt("Property insurance: ");

    // logic
    mi = interest_rate / 1200;
    base = 1;
    mbase = 1 + mi;
    paid = (price * paid_in_percent) / 100;
    for (i = 0; i < year * 12; i++) {
        base = base * mbase;
    }
    pi = (price - paid) * mi / (1 - (1 / base));
    monthly_tax = (property_tax * price) / (1200 * year);
    monthly_insurance = annual_insurance / 12;
    monthly_total = pi + monthly_tax + monthly_insurance;

    // output
    alert(
        "Monthly prin + int: " + pi + "\n"
      + "Monthly tax: " + monthly_tax + "\n"
      + "Monthly insurance: " + monthly_insurance + "\n"
      + "Total Payment: " + monthly_total + "\n"
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great . As I am using HTML <input> to take the inputs. So how do I connect <input id="purcahse-price" class="form-control" type="text" name="sPrice" placeholder="Default" > to 

    price            = +prompt("Purchase price: ");

Comment: you can use [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to reference an _Element_, then access it's `.value`